# How to center a CheckBox below a EditText without using nested layouts?

Tags: android, layout, centering

In the screenshot below, the checkbox is not centered below the edittext above. How can I center the checkbox so that it is centered right below the edittext? 
 
 
[image]

The layout I am using to generate the above UI is:

**Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:padding="5dip"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:text="text 1"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"

    android:padding="5dip"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="1"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"

    android:text="check"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Things, I have already tried on the CheckBox widget with no success:

1. `android_layoutAlignRight` with the EditText widget.
2. `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" on the relative layout

I know I can achieve the 'centering' by nesting the CheckBox in another relative layout and using `android:layout_gravity="center"` on the inner relative layout but I would prefer a solution that avoids nested layouts.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: "I would prefer a solution that avoids nested layouts." Why do you want to avoid nesting layouts?

Comment: @MisterSquonk Because, introducing a nested layout simply to center a widget seems inefficient if there is a non-nested way to accomplish the same look.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't think that is possible unless you want to add padding to the checkbox on the left so it moved to the center of the edittext. You can do it, but that is not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the box and the text centered?  If you set the gravity to the Checkbox to center and use fill parent for width then you can Center just the text.  But the Center on it will still be off from the editText1 because the Box itself is going to eat into the total width to center.

If you use a custom graphic toggle button instead then you could easily accomplish what you want by using a .9 file and would probably look better overall graphically speaking (same Gravity: Center, Width: Fill Parent from above)

Otherwise I think you have to nest it.

Comment: Can you clarify how a .9 file would center the checkbox?

Comment: Using a .9 file allows you to create a custom Toggle/Checkbox that supports text.  When you implement it, you would stray towards the button side, (i.e. have the text within the button).  Once you do this, you can use:

Comment: android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center" on the button, which will center the text and use the .9 file to stretch appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using a RelativeLayout, try

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Ok, then you can use the TableLayout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1"> 

<TableRow>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="5dip"          
    android:text="text 1"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
    android:padding="5dip"      
    android:gravity="center"                
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="1"/>

   </TableRow>

   <TableRow>

  <View/> 

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"                  
    android:text="check"/>

 </TableRow></TableLayout>
```

The empty  node is an intentional hack, to force the check box into 'column' 1 rather than column 0.

This gives the following:

[image]

Comment: You need to also remove the layout_toRightOf attribute. This will centre it in the screen but not in the centre of the edit text box.

Comment: Well, I do not want to center it in the screen but center it relative to the textbox.

Comment: Using the TableLayout above will center the checkbox relative to the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty simple solution to this, even though it requires using a **RelativeLayout**:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/remember_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="@string/remember_settings"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the code as stated above, both **layout_width** and **layout_centerInParent** in the **CheckBox** must be set accordingly to the example above: otherwise, it won't work.

Additionally, if the **parent** of the **RelativeView** is set to fill the entire screen, you can set the **layout_width** of the RelativeView to **match_parent**, otherwise it must be set to **fill_parent**.

Hope this helps for anyone out there, as I have been struggling quite a bit with it myself.